# Convert XML to JSon to c# object

Tags: c#, json, xml

As part of dynamic documents proccesor app we must migrate thousands of documents from XML to Json. This is my approach.

I have this Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <syscur_historial_schema>
        <strtipoobj>OM_SECCION</strtipoobj>
        <strnombreobj>_1_Seccion_IDENTIFICACION_DEL_PACIENTE</strnombreobj>
        <numobj>0.00</numobj>
        <txtpropsobj/>
        <txtprostit><![CDATA[BackColor = 14171687,BorderStyle = 0,FontBold = .F.,FontItalic = .F.,FontName = "Tahoma",FontSize = 9,FontUnderline = .F.,ForeColor = 0,AutoSize = .F.,BackStyle = 1,LineColor = 14171687, TitleWidth=100, CAPTION="IDENTIFICACION DEL PACIENTE"]]>
        </txtprostit>
        <strencabezado>IDENTIFICACION DEL PACIENTE</strencabezado>
    </syscur_historial_schema>
```

I converted it to JSon:

[image]

Then I need to deserialize that JSon into this c# class:

```
public class syscur_historial_schema
{
    public string strtipoobj { get; set; }
    public string strnombreobj { get; set; }
    public string numobj { get; set; }
    public string txtpropsobj { get; set; }
    public string txtprostit { get; set; }
    public string strencabezado { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Converter:

```
public class ConvertXmlToJson
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convierte un archivo con formato XML en fornato JSon 
    /// usando JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string XmlToJsonSerializeXmlNode<T>(string xmlPath, string nodeName, bool cleanString)
    {
        string justPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlPath);
        string json = Path.Combine(justPath, $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlPath)}.json");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        if (cleanString)
            doc.LoadXml(CleanRepeatedSpaces(File.ReadAllText(xmlPath)));
        else
            doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(xmlPath));

        XmlNodeList nodes = GetNode(doc, nodeName);
        List<T> lista = new List<T>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string jSonNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
            T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jSonNode);
            lista.Add(obj);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(json, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista));
        return json;
    }

    public static XmlNodeList GetNode(XmlDocument doc, string nodeName)
    {
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName(nodeName);
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

And this test Method

```
[TestMethod]
public void Tools_ConvertXmlToJson_Tests()
{
    string path = "D:\\MyXmlPath\\";
    string xml = Path.Combine(path, "MyXmlFile.hist");
    string jsonFile = ConvertXmlToJson.XmlToJsonSerializeXmlNode<syscur_historial_schema>(xml, "syscur_historial_schema",true);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, File.Exists(jsonFile));
    List<syscur_historial_schema> jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<syscur_historial_schema>>(File.ReadAllText(jsonFile));
}
```

Now my problem is my Deserialized object always return null on every property, I was thinking the problem is CDATA node.

**Questions**

1- What I'm doing wrong ?

2- How to convert xml CDATA to Json string ?

Comment: Why are you going from XML to JSON and then to a C# object? Why not just deserialize the XML into a class? It would probably handle that CData section just fine.

Comment: @JLRishe I must convert a lot of files from xml to json as part of migration plan. And My XML schema is very old.  I don't need to convert full xml. just some nodes from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your syscur_historial_schema class serialized like this:

```
[Serializeable]     
public class syscur_historial_schema
{
 public string strtipoobj { get; set; }
 public string strnombreobj { get; set; }
 public string numobj { get; set; }
 public string txtpropsobj { get; set; }
 public string txtprostit { get; set; }
 public string strencabezado { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the xml into the class like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(syscur_historial_schema));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
var schema = (syscur_historial_schema)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Then convert schema into json like this:

```
 string json = JsonConverter.SerializeObject(schema);
```

You don't have to convert the xml string into an xml document prior to converting it to a class object. Straight deserialize the xml string directly into the class object.

Comment: Tks for your approach. What is the NS for Serializeable property ?

Comment: It's an attribute...no namespace. Above the class declaration, just start typing "[" and it should appear with intellisense.

Comment: @dickrichie Well...it's [technically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `System` namespace.

Comment: @dickrichie Yep. you have a Typo at [Serializeable]  must be [Serializable]

Comment: Ha! I'm a bad speller. Thank the gods for intellisense and google!

Comment: @dickrichie Yep.. Thanks  god for intellisense and BING !!! Don't like google….. And tks for your approach.